# Procedure or function deleteprofile has too many arguments specified

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a web application using asp.net on my gridview im using a command field edit button that calls a stored procedure for updating the data but while updating

I'm getting the following error:

> Procedure or function updateprofile has too many arguments specified.
>
> Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>       Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>       originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function updateprofile has too many
>   arguments specified.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[updateprofile] 
   @pid int, 
   @pfirstname varchar(50), 
   @plastname varchar(50), 
   @padress varchar(50),
   @pemail varchar(50),
   @ptelephone varchar(50), 
   @pbirthday date 
as begin 
   update profile 
   set firstname = @pfirstname, @plastname = lastname,
       @padress = adress, @pemail = email, @ptelephone = telephone,
       birthday = @pbirthday 
   where id = @pid end
```

And this is my asp code:

```
SelectCommand="selectAllProfile" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"     
UpdateCommand="updateprofile" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
DeleteCommand="deleteprofile" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure"

<UpdateParameters>
  <asp:Parameter Name="pid" Type="Int32" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="pfirstname" Type="String" /> 
  <asp:Parameter Name="plastname" Type="String" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="padress" Type="String" /> 
  <asp:Parameter Name="pemail" Type="String" /> 
  <asp:Parameter Name="ptelephone" Type="String" /> 
  <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="pbirthday" /> 
</UpdateParameters>
```

btw im facing the same error for the delete command

this is my vb code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports Class1e

Public Class Profile_test
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim rc As Integer
Dim inc As Integer
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim x As New Class1e
Protected Sub Btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles  
Btn_save.Click

    If id_txt.Text.Length = 0 Then
        x.insertProfile(fname_txt.Text, lname_txt.Text, adresss_txt.Text,  
email_txt.Text, birthday_txt.Text, phone_txt.Text)
        id_txt.Text = "0"
    Else
        x.updateProfile(id_txt.Text, fname_txt.Text, lname_txt.Text,  
  adresss_txt.Text,  
 email_txt.Text, birthday_txt.Text, phone_txt.Text)
    End If
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles  
GridView1.Load
    GridView1.Columns(1).Visible = False

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)  
Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.SelectedRow
    id_txt.Text = row.Cells(1).Text
    fname_txt.Text = row.Cells(2).Text
    lname_txt.Text = row.Cells(3).Text
    adresss_txt.Text = row.Cells(4).Text
    email_txt.Text = row.Cells(5).Text
    phone_txt.Text = row.Cells(6).Text
    birthday_txt.Text = row.Cells(7).Text
End Sub

Protected Sub btn_new_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles  
btn_new.Click
    fname_txt.Text = ""
    lname_txt.Text = ""
    adresss_txt.Text = ""
    email_txt.Text = ""
    phone_txt.Text = ""
    birthday_txt.Text = ""
    id_txt.Text = ""
End Sub
```

This is my vb class code:

```
Public Class Class1e
Dim x As String
Public Sub New()

End Sub

Public connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestConnectionString").ConnectionString
Public cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

Public Sub updateProfile(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fname As String, ByVal lname As String, ByVal adress As String, ByVal email As String, ByVal birthday As String, ByVal phone As String)

    Try
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("updateprofile", cn)
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", id)
        If fname.Length = 0 Then
            MsgBox("First name is a required file")
        Else
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pfirstname", fname)

        End If

        If lname.Length = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Last Name is a required file")
        Else
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plastname", lname)
        End If

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@padress", adress)

        If email.IndexOf(".") = -1 Or email.IndexOf("@") = -1 Then
            MsgBox("The email format should be name@domain.com")
        Else
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pemail", email)
        End If

        If phone.Length = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Tel is a required file")
        Else
            If phone.Length <> 8 Then
                MsgBox("The tel should be 8 digits")
            Else
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptelephone", phone)
            End If
        End If

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pbirthday", birthday)

        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cn.Open()
        End If

        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("1 Record updated ")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub deleteProfile(ByVal id As Integer)

    Try
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("deleteprofile", cn)
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", id)

        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cn.Open()
        End If
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("1 Record deleted ")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub insertProfile(ByVal fname As String, ByVal lname As String, ByVal adress As String, ByVal email As String, ByVal birthday As String, ByVal phone As String)


    Try
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("insertprofile", cn)
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        If fname.Length = 0 Then
            MsgBox("First name is a required file")
        Else
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pfirstname", fname)

        End If

        If lname.Length = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Last Name is a required file")
        Else
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plastname", lname)
        End If

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@padress", adress)

        If email.IndexOf(".") = -1 Or email.IndexOf("@") = -1 Then
            MsgBox("The email format should be name@domain.com")
        Else
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pemail", email)
        End If

        If phone.Length = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Tel is a required file")
        Else
            If phone.Length <> 8 Then
                MsgBox("The tel should be 8 digits")
            Else
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptelephone", phone)
            End If
        End If

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pbirthday", birthday)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pprocessed", 0)
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cn.Open()
        End If

        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("1 Record inserted ")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
  End Sub
End Class
```

Awaiting your reply

Your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: i added the error for the updatecommand

Comment: Try adding birthday as Date instead of String ( vb code )

Comment: it did not change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**instead of giving**

```
set firstname = @pfirstname, lastname=@plastname,adress = @padress, 
                email = @pemail,telephone = @ptelephone,birthday = @pbirthday 
                where id = @pid
```

**u have given**

```
set firstname = @pfirstname, @plastname = lastname,@padress = adress, 
                @pemail = email, @ptelephone = telephone,birthday = @pbirthday 
                where id = @pid
```

Comment: i fixed it as u suggested and i'm still getting the same error

Comment: My procedure is working very well ! i'm using the same procedure in another page and it's working perfectly !

Comment: Can u paste your vb.net code for update here.so that i can frame what is the error.

Comment: Simply give breakpoint and check this.We ll get to know where error hits.

Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("updateprofile", cn)
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", ID)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pfirstname", fname)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plastname", lname)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@padress", adress)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pemail", email)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptelephone", phone)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pbirthday", birthday)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: this function is working fine it's for another button! my error is when i press EDIT on the GRIDVIEW !! on this click i'm not calling any function i'm just using a stored procedure in the sql data source

Comment: NO need to call any stored procedure during edit click.In gridview we have ITEMTEMPLATE and EDITITEMTEMPLATE.IN the page load, display only values in gridview.On edit click make the values as display in textbox, so that you can edit and update.For reference      http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET-2-0

Comment: can you give it to me in vb.net?

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VBASPNETGridView-19039173/sourcecode?fileId=22700&pathId=1132833945. If you want quick goto converter.telerik.com and convert c# code to vb.Net in few seconds.